# Typescript compiler not erroring on const with explicit type

Tags: typescript

I'm assuming this is intentional behavior, but it's unexpected.  Given the following:

```
interface Foo {
  foo: number
}

interface Bar {
  bar: Foo
}

const BAR = 'bar'
const BAR2: string = 'bar'

function getBar(bar: Bar): boolean {
  return bar[BAR].foo // error, typescript can discern the value of `BAR` and reports that `number` is not assignable to `boolean`.
}

function getBar2(bar: Bar): boolean {
  return bar[BAR2].foo // typescript appears to not be able to discern the value of `BAR2`
}
```

I would have expected Typescript to be abel to discern the value of `BAR2` and thus, be able to discern the type and error on an invalid function return type like `getBar` is doing.  But it appears Typescript only knows that `BAR2` is a `string`.

**NB**: turning on `noImplicitAny` will expose a *different* error on `getBar2` because there's no index signature on `Bar`

Can someone please shed some light on why the explicit typing on a const results in this behavior?

Comment: Can you please be a little more explilcit?  Do you mean strings can be _cast_ to booleans?  Also, that's not really what the crux of the issue is, rather, why can't Typescript discern the value of the const since it's being set explicitly?

Comment: Ugh, nevermind. I made a mistake. Coercion, conversion, casting. It all means the same.   I don't understand what "discern the value of BAR2" means. `foo` does not have the right type? What is wrong actually?

Comment: No worries.  The issue is that Typescript can determine the value when explicitly initializing a const to a value without a type.  But when one explicitly declares a type, it's no longer able to determine the explicit initialization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TypeScript gave the variable `BAR` the type `"bar"` because that was its initializer. This means that `bar[BAR].foo` is `number` because `bar.bar.foo` is `number` and those things mean the same thing.

With `BAR2`, you explicitly overrode the inference so it has the type `string` instead of the type `"bar"`. When you index an object by a string, you get an implicit `any`.

Comment: So I followed everything except for the "explicitly overrode the inference" - it's still a `string`, no?  And it still should be able to discern the explicit value since it's initialized as such, right?

Comment: It's the *type* of the variable being the string literal type `"bar"` that causes the lookup to resolve to a known variable. The `: string` annotation **means** "This variable *is* of type `string`", so that resolution no longer occurs.

Comment: Ah.  Got it.  Cheers.